# plpgsql extract array before loop on it's elements

Tags: json, postgresql, loops, plpgsql, jsonb

I am trying to create a plpg function taking as parameter :

```
[{'id_product': 100000158, 'd_price': '7,75'}, {'id_product': 100000339, 'd_price': '9,76'}]
```

Or maybe :

```
{'products': [{'id_product': 100000158, 'd_price': '7,75'}, {'id_product': 100000339, 'd_price': '9,76'}]}
```

Can't tell the best approach yet.

I want to transform this jsonb object or string to an array so I can loop on it.
The idea is to loop en every `{'id_product': xxxxxxxxx, 'd_price': 'xxxxx'}` so I if values are the same in a table.

What's the most optimal way to do this ?
I am still playing with jsonb functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for those who might want to do something similar :

I changed the input to something like : `{0: [100000158, 7.76], 1: [100000339, 9.76]}`

And function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_d_price(
    p_products jsonb)
    RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
        _key varchar;
        _real_price NUMERIC;
        _bad_price jsonb;
BEGIN

    FOR _key IN (
        SELECT jsonb_object_keys(p_products)
    )
    LOOP
        SELECT ei.price INTO _real_price FROM product pr JOIN ecom_input ei ON (pr.ecom_id,pr.sku) = (ei.ecom_id,ei.sku_supplier) WHERE pr.id = (p_products->_key->>0)::INT;
        IF _real_price <> (p_products->_key->>1)::NUMERIC THEN
                _bad_price = COALESCE(_bad_price,'{}'::jsonb) || jsonb_build_object((p_products->_key->>0)::TEXT,
                                                                                    jsonb_build_object('d_price', p_products->_key->>1,'new_price', _real_price));
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN _bad_price;

END;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function containing `JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET()` function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_extract_elements( i_jsonb JSONB )
RETURNS TABLE (o_product VARCHAR(500), o_price VARCHAR(500))
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY

WITH tab AS 
(
 SELECT *
   FROM JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET(NULL::record,i_jsonb )
      AS tab(id_product VARCHAR(500), d_price VARCHAR(500))
 )
SELECT *
  FROM tab;

END 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and invoke in such a way that

```
SELECT *  
  FROM fn_extract_elements(
'[{"id_product": "100000158", "d_price": "7,75"}, 
  {"id_product": "100000339", "d_price": "9,76"}]'
);

o_product   o_price
100000158   7,75
100000339   9,76
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=263f3307c0ac57dc0ff3202dec79550e)</kbd>